# Behat3 Subcontexts

Tags: php, bdd, behat

Previous versions of Behat used useContext to include subcontexts and execute them. My question is how can I include SubContext in Behat3 ?

I tried looking into Behat3 documentation but it looks like the link is broken, also tried searching stackoverflow but still no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
//behat.yml
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts: [FeatureContext, SubContext]
```

---

```
//FeatureContext.php
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;

class FeatureContext implements Context {
    private $subContext;

    /** @BeforeScenario */
    public function fetchContexts(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        $environment = $scope->getEnvironment();

        $this->subContext = $environment->getContext('SubContext');
    }

    /** @When I do something on :foo */
    function IDoSomethingOnFoo($foo) {
        $this->subContext->doSomethingOnFoo($foo);
    }
}
```

---

```
//SubContext.php
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;

class SubContext implements Context {

    function doSomethingOnFoo($foo) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I didn't tested it but I'm pretty confident that this will answer to your question.

Comment: I already found the solution here https://gist.github.com/stof/930e968829cd66751a3a but saw this. I appreciate your answer and will accept it :-)

Comment: This is actually documented: http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/context_communication.html